# AdMob banner's visibility stuck to View.GONE

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I've been having this problem for weeks now. I finally narrowed it down to this : the AdView's visibility seems stuck to `View.GONE`, no matter how hard I try to set it to `View.VISIBLE`.

Here is my code :

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    AdView bannerView;

    RelativeLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(this);
        AppLovinPrivacySettings.setHasUserConsent(false, this);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"); // test APP ID

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        game = new GameClass(this);

//      // Create Layout that will call both Libgdx View and AdMod View
        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // InitializeCommonRessources Libgdx View
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
//
        View gameView = initializeForView(game, config);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        // Tell Android to use this Layout
        setContentView(layout);

        setupBanner();
    }

    @Override
    public void setupBanner() {
        SetupAdMobBanner();
    }

    public void SetupAdMobBanner() {
        System.out.println("Setup AdMob BANNER");

        bannerView = new AdView(this);

        bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // These are my desperate attempts to make the banner visible
        System.out.println("visibility == " + bannerView.getVisibility()); // Always prints "visibility == 8" which is the value for View.GONE (View.VISIBLE is 0)

        bannerView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override public void onAdOpened() {
                System.out.println("BANNER AD OPENED");
                Ressources.incrementBannerClicks();
            }

            @Override public void onAdClosed() {
                System.out.println("BANNER AD CLOSED");
            }

            @Override public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                System.out.println("BANNER LEFT APP");
            }

            @Override public void onAdFailedToLoad(int var1) {
                System.out.println("BANNER FAILED TO LOAD : " + var1);
                destroyAdMobBanner();
                SetupAdMobBanner();
            }

            @Override public void onAdLoaded() {
                System.out.println("BANNER LOADED");
                bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("visibility == " + bannerView.getVisibility());
            }

            @Override public void onAdImpression() {
                System.out.println("BANNER IMPRESSION");
            }
        });

        bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("visibility == " + bannerView.getVisibility());

        bannerView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

        bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("visibility == " + bannerView.getVisibility());

        bannerView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"); // Test banners

        bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("visibility == " + bannerView.getVisibility());

        bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("visibility == " + bannerView.getVisibility());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        layout.addView(bannerView, adParams);

        bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("visibility == " + bannerView.getVisibility());

        loadAdMobBanner();

        bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("visibility == " + bannerView.getVisibility());
    }

    public void loadAdMobBanner() {
        System.out.println("BANNER loadAd(adRequest)");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("36429449DBD95B918CFD96E610995AE6").build(); // Test ads for my Honor 7x
        bannerView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void destroyAdMobBanner() {
        if (bannerView == null) return;

        System.out.println("Destroying BANNER");

        layout.removeView(bannerView);
        bannerView.destroy();
        bannerView = null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am desperately trying to set the visibility to VISIBLE, but it always prints `visibility == 8` right after (8 being the value for GONE, VISIBLE's being 0).

The weirdest thing is that **sometimes, the banner will actually show up**.
It might work for a day or two, and suddenly not work for a day or two, the banner won't show even though the AdListener says it's been successfully loaded, *without me doing a damn thing*.

The problem occurs on a physical device, a Honor 7X, with both live ads and test ads.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add test device to adView. You will find test device id in logcat. If you don't add test device while development and click on ads for many times ads will stop working for that ad id.

Comment: I did add a test device. The ads do say "Test ad" when they appear. And as I said, even test ads (with the test ad unit) are not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add only this code not set visibility

try this code

```
private AdView mAdView;

mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
                .addTestDevice("36429449DBD95B918CFD96E610995AE6")
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.resume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

I hope that can help you!

Thank You.